# Replace multiple symbols in kotlin string

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to construct string from this:

```json
"title": {
    "text": "{0} shared a feeling",
    "actions": [
        {
            "text": "User+021122",
            "action": "some_action"
        }
    ],
    "badgeName": "avatar-5"
}
```

So i need not to replace `{0}` with `actions[0].text`.
I also can have multiple actions and initial text like

```
"{0} shared a feeling and {1} did nice job"
```

Comment: What is `actions[0].text` ? Maybe if you share some more code it might be easier.

Comment: actions[0].text is string. I get this from backend and I need manually in android app to construct correct string. As you see initially text is {0} shared a feeling . I need now to loop over actions and on index 0 replace {0} with User+021122.

Comment: what you have there is called a `Json`. Use any json parser you want, and you can create a pojo from it. Then you can use it like any other object and get whatever you want from it. I don't know about android libraries, personally I use jackson for json parsing, but there are others, for example gson.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are getting a given String that represents a message format, and you want to replace placeholders with actual text. You can use Java's [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) to do so:

```
import java.text.MessageFormat

val pattern = "{0} shared a feeling and {1} did nice job"

val result = MessageFormat.format(pattern, "John", "Carl")
println(result)
```

This prints:

```
John shared a feeling and Carl did nice job
```

Of course, in your case the actual text is coming as part of the JSON, so it's just a matter of extracting the information you need from the JSON (you can use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) to do so, for example) and then use `MessageFormat` as described above.